# XPage rest service - can I search without using the full text index?

Tags: rest, xpages, xpages-extlib

Xpage rest service searching is limited when searching because of full text index.

In our environment we have some rather large databases.  In our grids we use xe:restService to surface data to a sencha grid framework.  This works great... until you need to search the grid.  The grid search works unless you get a result with a ton of data and hit the full text limit.  We've raised the limit on the server to upwards of 100k only to have it crash during regular operation.

Are there any other options?  I am not really sure what it would be but I though I would ask.

Comment: DQL would be the first thing that comes to my mind, but I don't think that already has full text support (correct me if I'm wrong...) and would require you to upgrade to 10.0.1. What do you mean with 'rather large'? Millions of documents?

Comment: I'd recommend on the server side checking the number of results and generating a different response if it's too many. Then on the client side, handle it to inform the user. If you've got more than 5000 search results, the user should be encouraged to use a more specific search. When you return 5000 results, how often would the user scroll through the whole grid? Personally I wouldn't, so as a developer I wouldn't consider it a good user experience to provide.

Comment: Depending on how structured the data are: I have an application running with a notes nsf database that has about 6 million (!!!) records. This has nothing to do with Rest so far .  The data are very structured and I perform searches based on view indexes and getalldocumentbykey with search arrays. So for my purposes this works like a charm and performance is outstanding. as I said already this has nothing to do with rest at all but I assume that it would be no difference. Let me know if this is an option for you. And as Stephen already mentioned results should be limited to reasonable amount

Comment: Thanks so much for the replies.  The searches are unstructured (users want to be able to search on anything) otherwise I would have used views and get docs by key.

I kind of ended up back where I was at - finding the highest threshold where the server wouldn't complain and then letting the user know that they didn't get a full result set if they hit it.